# Decode all properties in custom init (enumerate over all properties of a class and assign them a value)

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decoder

I'm currently working on a project that it's API isn't ready yet. So sometimes type of some properties changes. For example I have this struct:

```
struct Animal: Codable {
    var tag: Int?
    var name: String?
    var type: String?
    var birthday: Date?
}
```

for this json:

```
{
    "tag": 12,
    "name": "Dog",
    "type": "TYPE1"
}
```

But in development, the json changes to something like this:

```
{
    "tag": "ANIMAL",
    "name": "Dog",
    "type": 1
}
```

So I get some **type mismatch** error in decoder and **nil object**. To prevent decoder from failing entire object, I implement a custom **init** and set **nil** for any unknown property and it works like charm (**NOTE: I'll handle these changes later and this is only for unplanned and temporary changes**):

```
#if DEBUG
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    tag = (try? container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .tag)) ?? nil
    name = (try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)) ?? nil
    type = (try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)) ?? nil
    birthday = (try? container.decodeIfPresent(Date.self, forKey: .birthday)) ?? nil
}
#endif
```

But for larger classes and struct, I have to write any property manually and it takes time and more importantly, sometimes I missed a property to set!

So is there any way to enumerate over all properties and set them?
I know I can get all keys from container but don't know how to set it's corresponding property:

```
for key in container.allKeys {
   self.<#corresponding_property#> = (try? container.decodeIfPresent(<#corresponding_type#>.self, forKey: key)) ?? nil
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of `Codable` is to provide a type safe and static way for encoding/decoding Swift types to/from JSON. The dynamic code you're looking for is not possible with Swift/Codable. Moreover, instead of masking mismatches between your client side data models and your API by this custom `init`, you should actually fix those issues. Also, using an API response design tool that automatically generates the code for making API requests/responses, like Swagger would save you from these kinds of errors.

Comment: The problem is that the _type_ of your values keeps changing: sometimes `tag` is a string, sometimes it's an integer. You're going to need a lot more than your Optional approach; that deals with whether something is present, not whether it has the right type. You'll need a StringOrInteger type as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215260/swift-4-json-decodable-with-multidimensional-and-multitype-array Either that or, as has already been suggested, just give up on Decodable altogether, since it is not appropriate if the API is going to dance around like this.

Comment: Yes I know, but when there is no documents for API and it's under development, we don't want this much crashes in debug mode. Actually I put the initializer inside     #if DEBUG ... #endif @DávidPásztor

Comment: If you have no control over the API, either wait for its development to be finished or use a mock server while its implementation fluctuates so much. If on the other hand you have control over the API design, make its developers use a tool better suited for getting around issues like this as explained before. Also, it's always better to catch such bugs in development as crashes rather than mask them using your approach and let the bugs leak into production accidentally.

Comment: Thanks @DávidPásztor. But the question is about the enumeration over all properties and assign them a value, not about this use case. I updated the question's title for more clarifying.

Comment: The only way to do that is through reflections using the [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) API, but again, I highly advice against doing that.

Comment: If keys and types can change heavily you are discouraged from using `Codable`. The magic of `Codable` – adopt the protocol and you are done – relies on consistent data.

Comment: is there any obligation using code able and deCodable ? use objectMapper handles all over this problems.less code no duplication code. I can modify your code if you want –

Comment: Yes @M0TRIX. I don't want any third party frameworks. By the way, `ObjectMapper` is a replace for `Codable`. It's not enumerates over all properties of a class and assign them a value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your particular example is that the *type* of your values keeps changing: sometimes `tag` is a string, sometimes it's an integer. You're going to need a lot more than your Optional approach; that deals with whether something is present, not whether it has the right type. You'll need a union type that can decode and represent a string or an integer, like this:

```
enum Sint : Decodable {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
    enum Err : Error { case oops }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let s = try? con.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(s)
            return
        }
        if let i = try? con.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .int(i)
            return
        }
        throw Err.oops
    }
}
```

Using that, I was able to decode both your examples using a single Animal struct type:

```
struct Animal: Decodable {
    var tag: Sint
    var name: String
    var type: Sint
}
let j1 = """
{
    "tag": 12,
    "name": "Dog",
    "type": "TYPE1"
}
"""
let j2 = """
{
    "tag": "ANIMAL",
    "name": "Dog",
    "type": 1
}
"""
let d1 = j1.data(using: .utf8)!
let a1 = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Animal.self, from: d1)
let d2 = j2.data(using: .utf8)!
let a2 = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Animal.self, from: d2)
```

Okay, but now let's say you don't even know what the keys are going to be. Then you need an AnyCodingKey type that can mop up the keys no matter what they are, and instead of multiple properties, your Animal will have a single property that's a Dictionary, like this:

```
struct Animal: Decodable {
    var d = [String : Sint]()
    struct AnyCodingKey : CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?

        init(_ codingKey: CodingKey) {
            self.stringValue = codingKey.stringValue
            self.intValue = codingKey.intValue
        }
        init(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
            self.intValue = nil
        }
        init(intValue: Int) {
            self.stringValue = String(intValue)
            self.intValue = intValue
        }
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)
        for key in con.allKeys {
            let result = try con.decode(Sint.self, forKey: key)
            self.d[key.stringValue] = result
        }
    }
}
```

So now you can decode something with complete unknown keys whose value can be string or integer. Again, this works fine against the JSON examples you gave.

Note that this is the inverse of what you originally asked to do. Instead of using the struct property names to generate the keys, I've simply accepted any key of either type and stored it flexibly in the struct through the use of the dictionary. You *could* also put a property façade in front of that dictionary using the new Swift 4.2 `dynamicMemberLookup` feature. But that is left as an exercise for the reader!

Comment: Thanks @matt but as I said, I don't want to handle every situation, This is just the case to demonstrate one of the situations and it's not going to be changing for ever.

Comment: I'm not finished. Wait.

Comment: Okay, there you go.

Comment: Thanks for your time to explain this. But as you said, this the inverse of what I originally asked. Also `dynamicMemberLookup` is for accessing members of a structure like a dictionary, type safe and with dot notation. What I asked is an automated flow to reduce repeated codes in the example initializer with something like enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you want is [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery). It's a meta-programming wrapper for Swift that will write the boilerplate for you, since you know what you want to write, it's just tedious (that's what Sourcery is ideal for). The important thing about Sourcery is (despite the name), there's no magic. It just writes Swift code for you based on other Swift code. That makes it easy to pull out later when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Nice tool. Thanks. Actually i'm looking for some pure swift code. Sourcery is kind of script that analysis the codes and write repeated code for me. The point is not writing them at all! DRY. Event don't DRY automatically or scripted.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. What does the output of a pre-compiler have to do with DRY? I don't understand what you mean by "not writing them at all!" Do you mean that since Swift compiler generally duplicates a lot of code when it specializes a generic function DRY forbids generic functions? This is a very strange requirement. (DRY is just a vague guideline anyway, like "minimize memory churn" or "prefer O(1) algorithms." It's not by itself a goal.) As specified, though, there is no solution to your problem in Swift today. Sourcery can solve the "it's tedious" problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extension.
In my case, If the type does not match, the default will be nil.

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
public func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
    do {
        let result = try decode(type, forKey: key)
        return result
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

public func decodeIfPresent(_ type: Int.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> Int? {
    do {
        let result = try decode(type, forKey: key)
        return result
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

public func decodeIfPresent(_ type: Bool.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> Bool? {
    do {
        let result = try decode(type, forKey: key)
        return result
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

public func decodeIfPresent(_ type: String.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> String? {
    do {
        let result = try decode(type, forKey: key)
        return result
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

public func decodeIfPresent(_ type: Double.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> Double? {
    do {
        let result = try decode(type, forKey: key)
        return result
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

public func decodeIfPresent(_ type: Float.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> Float? {
    do {
        let result = try decode(type, forKey: key)
        return result
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```